# Freshly installed Office 2007 doesn't have spell & grammer check for foreign languages

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007

Exactly what the title says. I wrote a text in Dutch and wanted to check the spelling and grammar. I press F7 and get notified that I don't have the proper tools installed.

The Office 2007 install I ded was a complete install, I still have the disc I bought.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

Comment: You're lucky, I just had to download it myself, since I didn't have it either ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to buy the language pack [from the Microsoft Office website](http://buy.trymicrosoftoffice.com/buyus/product.aspx?r=US_USD&family=langpack&culture=en-US) which about $25

In your case follow [this link](http://emea.microsoftstore.com/nl/Microsoft/OLP-2007-Nederlands) for the Dutch version

[Description:](http://buy.trymicrosoftoffice.com/buyus/product.aspx?r=US_USD&family=langpack&culture=en-US)

> Microsoft Office Language Packs for
>   2007 are designed to meet the needs of
>   multilingual individuals, families and
>   small businesses that routinely create
>   or edit documents and presentations in
>   different languages. Language Packs
>   offer a simple and cost-effective
>   solution that provides all of the
>   power of a fully localized version of
>   Microsoft Office. Available in more
>   than 35 different languages, Language
>   Packs, which are sold individually,
>   can be installed onto any other
>   language version of the 2007 Microsoft
>   Office suites or programs.
>
> You will have the ability to customize
>   your Office experience and to easily
>   switch between your base language and
>   your installed languages for your:
>
> - User Interface
> - On and Offline Help (including access to localized Office Online
>     resources)
> - Office Document Proofing and Editing Tools.

Answer (score 1):

I really thought it was free, however I have just looked on the website and it looks like the policy has changed

[Here is a page showing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/suites/HA102113701033.aspx) the localized version then what languages you get for free.

For anything else, you need to buy a [language pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/suites/FX102113661033.aspx).

Comment: Technically you're correct, but some versions of Office are probably bought in English only

Comment: Yes - However, my link shows that if you buy in English, you get - French, Spanish thrown in.

Comment: Link for Office 2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/language/office-2010-suites-localized-versions-HA101828838.aspx

Comment: Broken image, any chance you have the original? :)

Comment: @Gareth - I am sorry, I have no idea what it was :(

Comment: No worries - I'll go ahead and remove it since the answer seems fine without it :)